# ECharts Legend "Complex" React Component

Tags: reactjs, echarts

I'm currently working on a chart in ECHARTS where I need to format the legend labels dynamically based on the data from my React application.
I only could get it to work trough renderToString, but this is client-side code . The value which gets used in RawIntlProvider is a react Component, which consists of  from react intl.

I NEED to use this value which already contains all metadata needed to format the number in the proper way. RenderedToString returns ->
`<div><div class="">28.8<span class="formattedNumberUnit"> <!-- -->kWh</span></div></div>`

```
      formatter: (seriesName) => {
    const component = renderToString(
      <RawIntlProvider value={intl}>
        {
          data
            .map((row) => row?.[stateParams?.group?.key])
            .find((row) => row?.["sortValue"] == seriesName)?.["value"]
        }
      </RawIntlProvider>
    );
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const formattedNumberHTML = parser.parseFromString(
      component,
      "text/html"
    );
    const element = formattedNumberHTML.querySelector("*");
    return element ? element.textContent.trim() : "";
  },
  orient: "horizontal",
  bottom: 0,
  left: "center",
},
```

any ideas on how to improve this ugly hack?

Problems: Echarts Legend only supports strings, Intl hook (needs to not break any hook-rules),....

Answer (score 1):

The React documents have a section about [removing `renderToString` from client code](https://Removing%20renderToString%20from%20the%20client%20code).

Example (not tested):

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { flushSync } from 'react-dom';


formatter: (seriesName) => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  const root = createRoot(div);

  const element = flushSync(() => {
    root.render(
      <RawIntlProvider value={intl}>
        {data
          .map((row) => row?.[stateParams?.group?.key])
          .find((row) => row?.["sortValue"] == seriesName)?.["value"]
        }
      </RawIntlProvider>
    );
  });

  return element.textContent.trim();
}
```

However, this looks like an overkill. You only need a number formatted with a unit. You don't really care about the HTML structure. I would probably use [Intl.NumberFormat() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat) directly on the value, to get the number formatted with the unit, however `kWh` is not [supported](https://formatjs.io/docs/polyfills/intl-numberformat#supported-units). It's unclear how React Intl formats the unit because it uses `Intl.NumberFormat()` under the hood. There's probably a library that supports this units, or you might write a specific function.